# Trying to install wireless network driver

Tags: drivers

I just bought the plexgear N300 antenna network adapter for my desktop with Ubuntu. I cant get the driver to work, any ideas? I downloaded the drivers, the install.sh file doesnt work. When I put it in Terminal and type my password, it says authentication wrong

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` and also to add a link to the driver file that you downloaded. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please post the exact command and error message you encountered. Do you have the correct password?